# Incompatible types: structure and scalar

Tags: c

Im at my first day with C and its a bit different to C#. I am trying to make a function return a struct and I cannot see any problems with my code, but I keep getting the error "Incompatible types: structure and scalar".

In my main.c I do this call

```
struct Position pos = GetPosition();
```

In my other source file I have the function defined:

```
struct Position getPosition(){
  struct Position pos;
  pos.latitude = 56;
  pos.longitude = 18;
  pos.time = 456;
  return pos;
}
```

I have the function defined in the header file and its included in my main.c file.
What misstake have I done?

Comment: This worms perfectly on ideone [demo](http://ideone.com/Ttnv48). Hint: C is case-sensitive.

Comment: *Im at my first day with C and its a bit different to C#* Understatement of the day ? :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably happening because you are calling `GetPosition` and you have declared `getPosition` (check case).

Because it hasn't seen a prototype the compiler plays pretend that there is a function `GetPosition` that returns an `int`. Everything else is correct.

Comment: Ah, so used to C# naming so did not even notice that it was calling GetPosition instead of getPosition. But after fixing it I still ended up with the same error. So then it must mean that it still cant find the function? http://ideone.com/F8BE0C for the full code.

Comment: @user1842278 Add a declaration before `main`. I.e. add this line before `main`: `struct Position getPosition();`. Or just move `main` way at the bottom.

Comment: I found the problem! It was of course the spelling misstake but also I could not do "struct Position pos = getPosition();". I had to split them for some reason into "struct Position pos; pos = getPosition();"

Comment: @user1842278 You can initialize from `getPosition` without problems, you don't need an additional step. Try smaller programs maybe ?

Comment: Try smaller programs? I copied this code and removed the printing http://ideone.com/Ttnv48 and it did not work until I splitted the initialization and assignment. Maybe it's a compiler error? No idea but it works when I split them so I guess thats the way I need to do.

Comment: @user1842278 It is "working" for the wrong reasons and will come back to bite you since you don't understand the actual issue (`struct Position` isn't declared before `main`).

Comment: @user1842278 the link you just posted is working, what is the problem?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah I just noticed there's a new ideone link. Yup that example looks correct :)